# Approximating $\chi_0$ pointwise with holomorphic functions

Tags: approximation, holomorphic-functions

Define $\chi_0:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ as

$$ \chi_0(z)=\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  1 \quad z=0\hfill \\
  0 \quad z\ne 0 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.$$

Does there exist a sequence of holomorphic functions converging pointwise to $\chi_0$?

Comment: The dirac function, extended radially?

Comment: $\chi_0$ is not the Dirac's delta function, but is the characteristic function of $0$.

Comment: That was intended to be a proposed answer.